# Spark connection to slave on standalone cluster

Tags: ssh

So I have my master node on my Mac and I can check on the webserver my master url as spark://private_ip_address:7077. Then I try to connect a slave node on a remote server.

So I run start-slaves.sh from the master and it creates a log on the remote server. So I assume that the ssh connection is ok. However the connection with the master is not possible as shown by the log content below.

```
21/01/12 13:06:36 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/01/12 13:06:36 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
21/01/12 13:06:36 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 127.0.0.0, and started at http://127.0.0.0:8081
21/01/12 13:06:36 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:06:48 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 1)
21/01/12 13:06:48 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:00 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 2)
21/01/12 13:07:00 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:12 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 3)
21/01/12 13:07:12 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:24 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 4)
21/01/12 13:07:24 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:36 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 5)
21/01/12 13:07:36 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:48 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 6)
21/01/12 13:07:48 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:08:36 ERROR RpcOutboxMessage: Ask terminated before connecting successfully
21/01/12 13:08:36 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored failure: java.io.IOException: Connecting to /master_node_private_ip_address:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
21/01/12 13:08:36 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:277)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to /master_node_private_ip_address:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:251)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:195)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
    ... 4 more
```

I tried to ssh from remote to local but it does not work. The public ssh key that I put in my local Mac is the root user key from the remote server. However I ssh the remote with a specific user name which is not root and which has no ssh key generated. So I though that ssh key may not apply system wide and tried to ssh back to the local Mac after doing a `sudo su root`. But it still does not work.

How can I ssh allow ssh from remote to local? I would be so grateful for some help to understand why this does not connect properly and show on the webserver the slave node.